# In HaxeFlixel, What is Box object and how to use it?

Tags: checkbox, haxe, haxeflixel

I'm trying to use `FlxUICheckBox`. In the official documentation, the constructor looks like this:

```
new(X:Float = 0, Y:Float = 0, ?Box:Dynamic, ..)
```

What is the `Box` object?

How should I send a `Box` object as a parameter to this constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should probably change it to `BoxAsset`. It's the image asset you want to use for the box part of the checkbox.

A simple checkbox has three components, and looks a bit like this:

```
[X] Checkbox
```

1. `Box` means the box part, `"[ ]"`
2. `Check` means the check part, `"X"`
3. `Label` means the text that goes in the textfield next to the checkbox

If you don't provide `Box` or `Check`, it will use default `FlxUIAssets` automatically to skin your checkbox. If you provide your own asset (such as `"assets/mybox.png"` for example), it will use that instead. It is expecting the same sort of thing you would pass into `FlxSprite.loadGraphic()` -- a `String`, a `BitmapData`, or a `FlxGraphic`.

I should probably also update the type from `:Dynamic` to `:FlxGraphicAsset`, I originally wrote this code a long time ago before they added that new helper type.